Task scheduler versus a service runnign in the background
Requirements -
I need to make some checks (system resources, licensing, gates, registry keys etc.) every 10 minutes and then take some action (say launch an app). I need to repeat this process every 10 minutes when the user's machine is not locked. I do not want to run this if the machine is locked.
I have two potential design solutions -
1- Implement a scheduled task that starts on Office Setup and then runs every 10 minutes.
2- Implement a service that starts on screen unlock and runs in the background all the time till the screen locks.
What are the pros and cons of each of these approaches and which one is a better design solution for this scenario?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
